Unexpected cost using Azure Application Insights for VS Code extension telemetry
I develop a VS Code extension, and I'd like to use Azure Application Insights for telemetry. I'm new to Azure, and what I need is a way to read crash reports and create simple charts to see what are the popular features, settings, etc. I use the advised @vscode/extension-telemetry package and followed the guide to create an Application Insights resource. I created and sent a test event which appeared in Application Insights, so it works.
However, in the Usage and estimated costs menu, I see a row Multi-step web tests with a Price of 9.36 EUR. I'm not sure what Multi-step web tests are, but according to the pricing page, they cost $10 per test per month. I didn't enable  Multi-step web tests manually. Do I need them for VS Code extension telemetry? If not, how can I disable them? If yes, do I have to pay $10 every month?
Edit: turned out that the Price column is the price of the service, not what I have to pay. There is no unexpected cost because I used that service 0 times, so I have to pay the Price 0 times.

Can you open Availability resource menu and check whether there are availability tests there?

It looks totally empty.

I don't think you need them for VS Code and I would be surprised if they added them on  your behalf (and even if some automation did it then you should have seen it in Availability resource menu). The best path forward is to open a support ticket and ask for explanation.

Feel free to send email to my SO alias  microsoft.com. I'll need either your resource name or resource id or application id (it is a part of a connection string) to take a closer look.
